# Performance optimization with modular addition when the modulus is of special form

Tags: c++, c, performance, math, assembly

I'm writing a program which performs millions of modular additions. For more efficiency, I started thinking about how machine-level instructions can be used to implement modular additions.

Let w be the word size of the machine (typically, 32 or 64 bits). If one takes the modulus to be 2^w, then the modular addition can be performed very fast: It suffices to simply add the addends, and discard the carry.

I tested my idea using the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int x, y, z, i;
    clock_t t1, t2;

    x = y = 0x90000000;

    t1 = clock();

    for(i = 0; i <20000000 ; i++)
        z = (x + y) % 0x100000000ULL;

    t2 = clock();

    printf("%x\n", z);
    printf("%u\n", (int)(t2-t1));

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling using GCC with the following options (I used `-O0` to prevent GCC from unfolding the loop):

```
-S -masm=intel -O0
```

The relevant part of the resulting assembly code is:

```
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+36], -1879048192
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [esp+36]
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+32], eax
    call    _clock
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+28], eax
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+40], 0
    jmp L2
L3:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [esp+36]
    mov edx, DWORD PTR [esp+32]
    add eax, edx
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+44], eax
    inc DWORD PTR [esp+40]
L2:
    cmp DWORD PTR [esp+40], 19999999
    jbe L3
    call    _clock
```

As is evident, no modular arithmetic whatsoever is involved.

Now, if we change the modular addition line of the C code to:

```
z = (x + y) % 0x0F0000000ULL;
```

The assembly code changes to (only the relevant part is shown):

```
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+36], -1879048192
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [esp+36]
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+32], eax
    call    _clock
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+28], eax
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+40], 0
    jmp L2
L3:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [esp+36]
    mov edx, DWORD PTR [esp+32]
    add edx, eax
    cmp edx, -268435456
    setae   al
    movzx   eax, al
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+44], eax
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR [esp+44]
    mov eax, 0
    sub eax, ecx
    sal eax, 28
    mov ecx, edx
    sub ecx, eax
    mov eax, ecx
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+44], eax
    inc DWORD PTR [esp+40]
L2:
    cmp DWORD PTR [esp+40], 19999999
    jbe L3
    call    _clock
```

Obviously, a great number of instructions were added between the two calls to `_clock`.

Considering the increased number of assembly instructions,
I expected the performance gain by proper choice of the modulus to be at least 100%. However, running the output, I noted that the speed is increased by only 10%. I suspected the OS is using the multi-core CPU to run the code in parallel, but even setting the CPU affinity of the process to 1 didn't change anything.

Could you please provide me with an explanation?

**Edit:** Running the example with VC++ 2010, I got what I expected: the second code is around 12 times slower than the first example!

Comment: The OS isn't going to automagically parallelize this.

Comment: Some modulus are harder than others. There isn't much more to that.

Comment: @ThomSmith: Yep. As I pointed above, my tests say the same thing.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that there is only 10% difference. Maybe the time is dominated by the calls to `clock()`? Try increasing the loop count.

Comment: @Henrik: I have already tried that, and there's no difference. I think much higher values for loop count results in more "context switches", which makes the timing more inaccurate.

Comment: @SadeqDousti If the system is sufficiently idle, context switches are rare enough that a larger loop count increases the meaningfulness of the timing (`clock()` on my system has a resolution of 10000 ticks, so for short-running benchmarks, small differences won't show up reliably). Also, you should make x, y, z volatile and compile with optimisations. I get a big difference with that (astonishingly, not with -O0, I don't see why).

Comment: @DanielFischer: If you look at the assembled code, it beccomes obvious why `O1` achieves much optimization over `O0`: As I described in the question, I used `O0` to prevent "unfolding" the loop. That is, if you use `O1`, the compiler observes that the loop does not do anything beyond computing z over and over again. Then, it optimizes this by removing the loop altogether! This is not what I want, since in the actual code (which I'm developing) things aren't this simple, and such optimizations are not possible.

Comment: @SadeqDousti Hence I made x, y, and z volatile, so the compiler can't eliminate the loop and has to perform the computation in each iteration. Without volatile, the loop is removed altogether, so both yield 0 timings. The thing is, with -O0, the time difference between the two loops is small, while with optimisations, it's about 50% (and more than 100% if I make x,y,z `unsigned long` to get 64 bits so the power-of-2 modulus cannot be completely removed). It's not surprising at all that -O1 makes the code much faster, that it makes the difference that much greater is (in this case).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the results? Do you actually want to use assembly in your code? Unless you have quite a bit of experience and/or know some specific tricks for this scenario, you are unlikely to beat the compiler by a relevant amoun. For anything else: What information do you hope to gather from measuring without optimizations?

Comment: @Grizzly: No, I don't plan on using assembly in my code. I just want to claim that, if the modulus is in the form 2^w, where w is the machine word size, the speed is almost doubled. In my experiments, I saw that this is usually the case (comparing 2^w to a modulus with no special form).

Comment: @SadeqDousti: Shouldn't you be comparing code compiled with optimizations in that case? You know since the performance benefit will be quite differently in that case (especially when it comes to things like auto vectorization).

Comment: You do realize that such comparisons at -O0 are utterly pointless, do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Art](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939410/art) [nailed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198920/performance-optimization-with-modular-addition-when-the-modulus-is-of-special-fo#comment16339830_12199989).

For the power-of-2 modulus, the code for the computation generated with `-O0` and `-O3` is identical, the difference is the loop-control code, and the running time differs by a factor of 3.

For the other modulus, the difference in the loop-control code is the same, but the code for the computation is not quite identical (the optimised code looks like it should be a bit faster, but I don't know enough about assembly or my processor to be sure). The difference in running time between unoptimised and optimised code is about 2×.

Running times for both moduli are similar with unoptimised code. About the same as the running time without any modulus. About the same as the running time of the executable obtained by removing the computation from the generated assembly.

So the running time is completely dominated by the loop control code

```
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+40], 0
    jmp L2
L3:
    # snip
    inc DWORD PTR [esp+40]
L2:
    cmp DWORD PTR [esp+40], 19999999
    jbe L3
```

With optimisations turned on, the loop counter is kept in a register (here) and decremented, then the jump instruction is a `jne`. That loop control is so much faster that the modulus computation now takes a significant fraction of the running time, removing the computation from the generated assembly now reduces the running time by a factor of 3 resp. 2.

So when compiled with `-O0`, you're not measuring the speed of the computation, but the speed of the loop control code, thus the small difference. With optimisations, you are measuring both, computation and loop control, and the difference of speed in the computation shows clearly.

Comment: Great. From your comments above and your answer here, I learned that I should use the keyword `volatile`, and compile with `O1`, to get correct results.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two boils down to the fact that divisions by powers of 2 can be transformed easily in logic instruction.

`a/n` where n is power of two is equivalent to `a >> log2 n`
for the modulo it's the same
`a mod n` can be rendered by `a & (n-1)`

But in your case it goes even further than that:
your value 0x100000000ULL is 2^32. This means that any unsigned 32bit variable will automatically be a modulo 2^32 value. 
The compiler was smart enough to remove the operation because it is an unnecessary operation on 32 bit variables. The ULL specifier 
doesn't change that fact.

For the value 0x0F0000000 which fits in a 32 bit variable, the compiler can not elide the operation. It uses a transformation that
seems faster than a division operation.

Comment: Or in the case where the modulus is 2^bitsize, it's a no-op. But the funny thing is, the OP didn't ask why it was slower, he asked why it wasn't as much slower as he expected.

Comment: +1. Good explanation. Just one point is left: Since the number of instructions between the two `_clock` calls is almost doubled in the second example, I naturally expect it to be 100% slower. Why is it just 10% slower? (You can run the result and check this)

Comment: @SadeqDousti You can't "naturally expect" that doubling the assembly instruction doubles the execution time. On the one hand, different instructions take a different amount of time. On the other, modern CPUs can often execute different instructions in parallel.

Comment: @SadeqDousti: the pure number of instruction isn't a good indicator for the performance on modern x86 processeors. The latency/thoughput of instructions can vary wildly. Additionally cache misses (though unlikely in this case) and instruction dependencies can have a huge effect by stalling the pipeline.

Comment: @SadeqDousti what's most likely taking time in the execution is the compare and conditional jump at the end of the loop. The rest of the instructions are trivially pipelined by the cpu and will take almost no time to execute. Instruction count rarely matters as long as you fit in the cache.

Comment: @DanielFischer, @Grizzly: I can't agree more. But if you look carefully at both results, you see that the first assembly has 5 `mov`s, 1 `add`, 1 `inc`, 1 `cmp`, and 2 jumps between the two `_clock`s. On the other hand, the second one has 11 `mov`s, 2 `add`s and 1 `sub`, 1 `inc`, 2 `cmp`s, 2 jumps, and a bunch of other instructions. While one should also consider the modes in which these instructions operate (register, immediate, etc.), a "natural" expectation is that the running time doubles.

Comment: @SadeqDousti: As mentioned the number of instructions isn't that important. How many instructions can be executed overlapping/in parallel, how the instructions are positioned in regards to the cache line, what instructions are executed can all be more important. So there is really nothing natural about your expectation. For example a `mov eax, edx` will simply rename the registers, making it almost free. As a side note: Are you counting the instructions inside and outside the loop? how does that make sense?

Comment: @Grizzly: Makes sense to me. Is there a way to see how instructions are pipelined by the processor? To response your question: I'm counting whatever instruction which resides between the two calls to `_clock`.

Comment: No Sedaq, you cannot expect that behaviour on modern out-of-order processor. The modern processors have several pipelines which 
can handle different instructions in different order than they were decoded. On intel processor there are 3 pipes which can handle the arithmetic instructions. In the best cases you will have 5 instructions executed simultaneously. For instance, your loop instructions cmp+jbe, which are 2 instructions in your program are decoded to 1 µOp. You cannot deduce from your instr how they will be executed in the processor. It is much complex than simple instruction counting.

Comment: You can look at Agner Fog's blog, he has a table with the latencies and throughputs and pipelines of all current x86 processors. http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf

Comment: @SadeqDousti: IIRC vtune and codeanalyst can do pipeline simulation for intel/amd cpus, though I'm not 100% certain. However I don't see how knowing the exact scheduling would help you. To understand it I too would recommend Agner Fog's optimization manuals.

Comment: @Grizzly: Incidentally, I'm just working with VTune! Thanks for the suggestion. Thanks to you and tristopia for suggesting Agner Fog's manuals, which seem like an invaluable resource!